# Issue with Rails namespaces and STI - Spiced up with autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would need some help with restructuring a Rails application. Below you can find the extra details. The main questions:

I modified the code after @Nathan suggestions. Got one step further to heaven but still can smell some sulfur.

- SOLVED: Why am I getting the error: "superclass mismatch for class Report"
- SOLVED: Can I have some guidelines, how to structure complex namespacings, extensions and STI in Rails4?
- After server restart, I get the error on the Spock main page: --"Unable to autoload constant Bridge, expected ...route goes here... app/models/spock/report/bridge.rb to define it"-- After refreshing the page, the error is gone. But still, indicates some problem. This is reproducible after every server restart. HINT: Possibly an autoload issue... Any idea is welcome.

Environment:

- WEBrick 1.3.1
- Rails 4.0.9
- Ruby 2.1.5

Error details:

```
Unable to autoload constant Bridge, expected ...route goes here... bridge.rb to define it

app/views/spock/spock/index.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_spock_spock_index_html_erb___3895075684249237486_132397353980'
app/views/spock/spock/index.html.erb:6:in `map'
app/views/spock/spock/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_spock_spock_index_html_erb___3895075684249237486_132397353980'
```

File structure:

```
/app/controllers/spock/spock_controller.rb
/app/controllers/spock/marketplaces_controller.rb
/app/controllers/spock/reports_controller.rb

/app/modules/spock/spock_connector.rb
/app/modules/spock/report.rb
/app/modules/spock/report/bridge.rb
/app/modules/spock/report/metric.rb
```

Files:

```
# application.rb
...
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'spock', '{**}')]
...

# routes.rb
namespace :spock do
  get '/', :to => 'spock#index'
  resources :marketplaces, only: [] do
    resources :reports,    only: [:show]
end

# spock_controller.rb
module Spock
  class SpockController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @report_categories = Spock::Report.distinct.pluck(:category)
...

# marketplaces_controller
module Spock
  class MarketplacesController < SpockController
  end
end

# reports_controller
module Spock
  class ReportsController < MarketplacesController
    helper SpockHelper
...

# spock_connector.rb
module Spock
  class SpockConnector < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection "spock_#{Rails.env}"
  end
end

# report.rb
module Spock
  class Report < SpockConnector
    attr_accessor :legal_entity
  end
end

# bridge.rb
module Spock
  class Bridge < Report
...

# metric.rb
module Spock
  class Metric < Report
...
```

Database:

```
/* reports table */
id, type,           category,
1   Spock::Bridge  Bridge
2   Spock::Metric  Metric
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. After a day of trial and error I found the cause of autoload issue.

If you find your self touching the autoload structure, that is a good sign on being on the wrong path.
So I removed the autoload path from the application.rb file.

And modified the STI classes a little bit, to match the Rails autoload logic;

```
# bridge.rb
module Spock
  class Report
    class Bridge < Report
...

# metric.rb
module Spock
  class Report
    class Metric < Report
...
```

Database:

```
/* reports table */
id, type,           category,
1   Spock::Report::Bridge  Bridge
2   Spock::Report::Metric  Metric
```

Including the STI classes in the superclass makes them able to be autoloaded from the subfolder without including explicitly the folder in the application.rb file.
The downside is that the classes absolute paths gets longer...

Answer (score 0):

You are opening/defining the `Report` class in 3 separate files.

In `report.rb`, you specify `::Spock::SpockConnector` as the superclass for `Report`, but in `bridge.rb` and `metric.rb`, you are *not* specifying an explicit superclass, so Ruby uses `Object` as its superclass.

You cannot have both `Object` *and* `::Spock::SpockConnector` as the immediate superclass of `Report`.

Solution:
  In all 3 files you need to use `class Report < ::Spock::SpockConnector`

As soon as you fix that, you will encounter a similar error, because you are opening `SpockConnector` in several files, once with `::ActiveRecord::Base` as the superclass, and other times with implicit `Object` as the superclass.

This is another contradiction, so in all files that open/define `SpockConnector`, you need to use `::ActiveRecord::Base` as the superclass.

As for your namespacing question, that's opinion-based, but I will say that in Ruby there is no *need* to nest subclasses inside namespaces.

For example, you *could* keep `Report`, `SpockConnector`, `Metric`, and `Bridge` all at the same namespace level:

```
module Spock
  class SpockConnector < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end

module Spock
  class Report < SpockConnector
  end
end

module Spock
  class Metric < Report
  end
end

module Spock
  class Bridge < Report
  end
end
```

The fully scoped names are then:

```
Spock::SpockConnector
Spock::Report
Spock::Bridge
Spock::Metric
```

Comment: Yes, I mixed the class scope with the superclass name... that was a dumb thing to do.